# c3.js Accessing data objects/lines

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I've been trying to figure out how to change the name of a line after the chart is drawn, before you read further know that I have read the examples and I am having a very specific problem.

to change the name, you use

```
chart.data.names({data1: name});
```

however, my name for data1 is dynamic.  so it could be L33T12-4 or whatever.

So, what i have is the string value of the name and also the index as it was drawn in the chart.

What I'm asking is how do I turn that into the object?

I have tried `chart.data.names[index]` and `chart.data[index]`, doesn't seem to go where i want it.

If I put the string value for the name, also no dice.

Comment: C3.js is very confusing with what it calls a name, so let's get the terminology straight.  In your code snippet above, let's call `data1` the key and `name` the display name.  You seem to be using the word name for both things.  So are you saying that you know the key and want to assign the series with that key a new display name?

Comment: Yes. Exactly.  In the case of c3, the key and name come from the first value in the data series for the line, which in my case is the unique identifier of the data.

Comment: to further clarify, the key is abcd. c3 wants me to say abcd:color or abcd:name   what I have is 'abcd':name or 'abcd':color and it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since I could find no way to do this, I had to write a large ugly clump of code. Basically, I shifted out the original name and I shifted datax where x is the index.  Then I changed the names, colors, etc after the fact using if index ==0 then data0 if 1 then data1 etc.

Then I had a glass of whisky and all was right in the world.